# Delete object in database using json-server

Tags: javascript, database, rest

Having trouble with this one....

I have an object of data, in my db. EG:

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "todo": "one",
      "date": "one",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "todo": "two",
      "date": "two",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

And I'm using json-server to manage my restful routing:
https://github.com/typicode/json-server

I'm looping through my DB objects, to display them in the DOM as so:

```
  function displayLastTask(lastTask) {
    individualTasks +=
      `<div class="todoStyle" id=${lastTask.id}>
        <p>Date: ${lastTask.date}: Task: ${lastTask.todo}</p>
        <button class="deleteButton" id="id">Delete</button>
      </div>`;
    tasksContainer.innerHTML = individualTasks;
    return tasksContainer;
  }
```

However, when I click on my delete button, I want ONLY that object array, to be deleted from the DB.

So far, on click, regardless of which delete button I click, all objects are deleted from the DB.

**What's the best way to do this?**

So far, I'm:
 - looping through all divs to get the div id, (which is the object ID).
 - And then passing this into a delete method.

But it doesn't seem to pass through, the sole id. But all of them.

Whats the best way to delete an id from a DB, onclick?

```
document.getElementById('tasksContainer').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    var id = divs[i].getAttribute('id');
    fetchService.deleteTodoTask(id);
  }
});

  function deleteTodoTask(lastTask) {
    const options = {
      method: 'DELETE'
    };
    return fetch(`${url}/${lastTask.id}`, options);
  }
```

Comment: Your questions doenst fit to stack overflows Q&A. Ask your question on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Or do you have some sort of Problem with this existing code?

Comment: Well, I'm just asking the best why to delete an id in a DB.....  the code was just to help add context. Doesn't have to use these functoins at all....